# something wrong with my STM32 USB MSC SDIO

Tags: stm32

I used to get some code from CubeMX to make STM32 as a sdcard reader.
but there is something wrong in write.windows tell me that something wrong with the disk driver.
btw,it works in fatfs read/unlink,i didn't try write also.
here is some important code:

```
MSD_Status BSP_SD_Init(void)
{
    cardHandle.Instance = SDIO;
    cardHandle.Init.ClockEdge = SDIO_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
    cardHandle.Init.ClockBypass = SDIO_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;
    cardHandle.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDIO_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
    cardHandle.Init.BusWide = SDIO_BUS_WIDE_1B;
    cardHandle.Init.HardwareFlowControl = 
    SDIO_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
    cardHandle.Init.ClockDiv = 2;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef sd_err = HAL_SD_Init(&cardHandle);
    if (sd_err != HAL_OK)
        return MSD_ERR;
    sd_err = HAL_SD_ConfigWideBusOperation(&cardHandle, SDIO_BUS_WIDE_4B);
    if (sd_err != HAL_OK)
        return MSD_ERR;
    return MSD_OK;
}
```

Comment: while in usb&msc mode.it's fake write...os shows that file copied in to disk,but is unreadable.

Comment: I think that the important code is in usbd_msc_if.c and usbd_msc.c.

Comment: that part works fine,i tried to use ram to simulate a usb msc device.it's ok

Comment: Have you tried to read and write the SD directly? witout USB, but using the same functions that are used in the USB MSC module. I worked with USB MSC over a F7, and I remember that I had to change someting there.

Comment: yes,i tried.SD can read but can not write...also i am focus on this problem.but it's CMD_RSP_TIMEOUT and ILLEGAL_CMD  errors while i called HAL_SD_WriteBlocks

Comment: Dou you use polling R/W or interrupt/DMA? Which priority has every interrupt (DMA & SDMMC<x>)?

Comment: Polling R/W mode,not DMA